# How to be notified each time Rails runs an initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, startup, initializer

For performance benchmarking, I'm trying to hook into the Rails boot cycle and capture timestamps when files in config/initializers are run. Is there any way to register a listener for each initializer being run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and unobtrusive solution would be...

You can add a file called `0000_initialize_initializer_listener.rb` to `config/initializers` which will make it load first,

in that file you define a class or a method that logs triggering of initialiers,

and then add that method call to every initializer file.

I am betting that you will find that all files get loaded at roughly the same time, bootup load time issues usually have nothing to do with the drag of the initializers,

if you just want to know "when did my rails proc get started and how long it took", you can add a benchmark log entry into `config/boot.rb` and in the initializers

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks. So far it looks like Bunder.require is the main drag so you're probably right.